# Modify File Names for Large Group of Excel Files in Folder

Tags: excel, windows, vba

I have a large amount of excel files with different names in a folder and I need to append -MN to the end of all the file names before the .xlsx extension. I've looked around the web for a solution but haven't had much luck finding a clear answer. This is a work assignment so no outside software can be downloaded. Something through the command line or a vba macro would be preferred. I tried using ren *.xlsx *-MN.xlsx in the command prompt when navgiated to the proper folder but it didn't produce the desired result.

**This is what i'm looking for:**

**examplefile.xlsx would become examplefile -MN.xlsx**

I tried this...

```
ren *.xlsx *-MN.xlsx
```

and I tried this...

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim myFilePath As String, myFileName, NewFileName As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
myFilePath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Ex Folder\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myFilePath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    myFileName = objFile.Name
    If Right(myFileName, 4) = ".xlsx" Then
        NewFileName = Replace(myFileName, ".xlsx", "-MN.xlsx")
        Name myFilePath & objFile.Name As myFilePath & NewFileName
    End If
Next objFile
MsgBox "Files Renamed"
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are ways with VBA to rename files ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=VBA+rename+file) has many results).

Comment: I don't know how to turn my previous comment into code. That is what I tried so far and it didn't work. I also tried ren *.xlsx *-MN.xlsx in the windows command prompt which didn't work either. It gave me a slightly different result than what i was lookiing for.

Comment: (Paste that code into your original post, and format it by highlighting and clicking the `{}` icon)

Comment: pasted code in my original post.

Comment: Does the code throw any errors? If so, what error, where? If not, does it run correctly? Step through it with `F8` and see where it skips a loop perhaps.

Comment: The code does not throw any errors. It just doesn't change the file names at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't produce the desired result"?  Your code works fine for me.  Have you checked the file and folder permissions?

Comment: What i mean is that the files in the folder remain unchanged like nothing ever happened.

Comment: The permissions are fine. I can rename the files from within the folder and from the windows command I listed above. The windows command changes the names of the files as well but just not to my desired result. I did do the step through like you mentioned and I thin it's skipping  NewFileName = Replace(myFileName, ".xlsx", "-MN.xlsx")
        Name myFilePath & objFile.Name As myFilePath & NewFileName

Comment: Ah! Change `If Right(myFileName,4)` to `Right(myFileName,5)`. Or change the string to just find `xlsx`, not `.xslx`, which is 5 characters.

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thank you so much! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim myFilePath As String, myFileName, NewFileName As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

myFilePath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Ex Folder\"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(myFilePath)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    myFileName = objFile.Name
    If Right(myFileName, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
        NewFileName = Replace(myFileName, ".xlsx", "-MN.xlsx")
        Name myFilePath & objFile.Name As myFilePath & NewFileName
    End If
Next objFile
MsgBox "Files Renamed"
End Sub
```